# inequality problem.

Tags: inequality

How do you managed to get from this :

$$\frac{1}{s-f(x)} \leq K$$

To this :

$$f(x) \leq s-\frac{1}{K}$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $s - f(x) > 0$, we can multiply both sides by $s - f(x)$, preserving the inequality. Then: $$\frac{1}{s-f(x)} \leq K \implies 1 \leq K(s-f(x)) = Ks - Kf(x)$$
Then, subtracting $Ks$: $$1-Ks \leq -Kf(x) \implies -1+Ks \geq Kf(x).$$
If $K > 0$, dividing by $K$ preserves the inequality and wields: $$f(x) \leq s - \frac{1}{K}.$$
Protip: Next time, do write all the hypothesis, what the variables are, what have you tried, and so on. In general, people doesn't have the patience to figure it all out by themselves, since you could have just told us.